# How to import only some icons with fontawesome JS API?

Tags: font-awesome, webpack-5, font-awesome-5

I fully read the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/import-icons).

I installed NPM dependencies and then in my `index.js`:

```js
import { library, icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faPlus)
```

And in my HTML

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
```

But the icon is not rendered.

What am I missing? I am using webpack 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `dom.watch()`

> without dom.watch(), automatic replacement of your Font Awesome icons
> won’t work in the rendered page!

```js
import { dom, library, icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faPlus)
dom.watch()
```

They don't mention in the docs. Now it's working and the bundle size is much lower.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `dom` before `use dom.watch()`

```js
import { dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
```